# Change colour of bars in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
 errorBar <- ggplot(ErrorAnalDF, aes(Task, ErrorPer, colour = Position))
    errorBar + stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "bar", position = "dodge", fill = "blue") +
      stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal, geom = "errorbar", position = position_dodge(width = 0.90), width = 0.2) +
     labs(x = "Task", y = "Error Percentage") + facet_wrap(~MuBack)
```

[image]

How do I get different colours for the fill of the bars (blue) for Head and Tail, like I have for the error bars and the borders?
I tried `errorBar + stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "bar", position = "dodge", fill = c("red","blue")`
or add fill in `labs(x = "Task", y = "Error Percentage", fill="Position")`

//edit: using `fill` instead of `colour`

```
errorBar <- ggplot(ErrorAnalDF, aes(Task, ErrorPer, fill = Position))
```

gives me this nasty looking graph
[image]

Comment: in your `ggplot(..., aes())` use `fill = position` instead of `colour = position`

Comment: didn´t work see edit

Comment: ah  took out fill in the stat.summary. Now it´s working fine. Thank you

Comment: if you have a working solution now, you can go ahead and post an answer to your own question (you may need to wait a little while).  (Please do *not* post the answer as an edit to your question ...)

Comment: @RichardTelford please post as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Leave out `fill=` in the first `stat.summary` and in your `ggplot(..., aes())` use `fill = position` instead of `colour = position`

```
errorBar <- ggplot(ErrorAnalDF, aes(Task, ErrorPer, fill = Position))
errorBar + stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "bar", position = "dodge") +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal, geom = "errorbar", position = position_dodge(width = 0.90), width = 0.2) +
 labs(x = "Task", y = "Error Percentage") + facet_wrap(~MuBack)
```

[image]